# How to define numbers in PyParsing?

Tags: pyparsing

I need to define a rule for integer numbers in PyParsing, something like:

```
import pyparsing
plusorminus = pyparsing.Literal('+') | pyparsing.Literal('-')
number = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums) 
hexdecimal = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.hexnums)
decimal = pyparsing.Combine(pyparsing.Optional(plusorminus) + number)
integer = pyparsing.Combine(pyparsing.Optional(plusorminus) + ((pyparsing.CaselessLiteral('0x') + hexdecimal) |number)).addParseAction(lambda toks: int(toks[0], 0))
```

The problem is with the trailings (non digits), for e.g. numbers and letter:

```
integer.parseString('123a').pprint()
```

doesn't return an error ?

Comment: Latest version of pyparsing includes several pre-defined integer and real expression definitions in `pyparsing.pyparsing_common` (https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.pyparsing_common-class.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `parsestring`, give it the parameter `parseAll=True`. Thus

```
integer.parseString('123a', parseAll=True).pprint()
```

throws an exception.

From the [pyparsing documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParserElement-class.html#parseString): *If you want the grammar to require that the entire input string be successfully parsed, then set parseAll to True.*